# I can't plot colors on the points of a graph of ellipses using the siber package

Tags: r, graph, colors, points

```
library(rjags)
library(coda)
library(sp)
library(splancs)
library(ggplot2)

rm(list=ls())
graphics.off()

set.seed(1) #to always get same results

library(SIBER)#the package I am using to deal with stable isotope data to infer isotopic niche

dados <- read.csv(file="siber_local_temporada_names.csv", sep=";" , header=T)

#first I create the siber object
siberobject <- createSiberObject(dados)

#than I establish community hulls colors
community.hulls.args <- list(palette(c("red","blue", "green", "black", "grey")), 
                             lty = 1, lwd = 1)

#than the group ellipses interval and number of reruns
group.ellipses.args  <- list(n = 10000, p.interval = 0.95, lty = 1, lwd = 4)

#than I plot the data
plot(dados$iso1,dados$iso2,xlab=expression({delta}^13*C~'\u2030'),
     ylab=expression({delta}^15*N~'\u2030'),
     xlim=c(-18,-11),ylim=c(7,16),
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n")
axis(1, at = seq(-18, -11, by = 2), las=2)
axis(2, at = seq(7, 16, by = 2), las=2)

##here is where I am having trouble, because the colors of the point aren't showing in my graph, as I am going to put an image.
points(dados$iso1,dados$iso2,pch=c(21,21,21,21,21)[dados$group],
       bg=c("darkred","darkblue", "darkgreen", "black", "grey")[dados$group], cex= 1.2)

##the legend shows with colors, but I have to order it according to the data, because the program doesn't put the legends on the right order.
legend("bottomright", c("Itapeva", "Lagoa do Peixe", "Passo de Torres", "Praia das Cabras", "Praia Grande"),
       fill=c("red","blue", "green", "black", "grey"), lty=0, bty="n")

## here SIBER plots the ellipses with colors
plotGroupEllipses(siberobject, n = 10000, p.interval = 0.95,
                  lty = 1, lwd = 2)
```

`R` doesn't show any error message, so I don't know where to begin to fix it. My data are on csv format as I always use because its easier on Macbook. My main problem is that the colors of the points aren't showing. `ggplot2` doesnt work very well on my computer too, but I have been able to build this this siber graph with colors before, and after I formatted my computer I couldn't do It. Thank you for any help you can give me!

**Edit**:

```
data: "siber_local_temporada_names.csv"
iso1    iso2    group   community
-13.051768  13.1703546  Passo de Torres 1
-13.2236656 12.5025446  Passo de Torres 1
-13.0476752 12.6545998  Passo de Torres 1
-13.03642   13.1035736  Passo de Torres 1
-13.0118632 13.0593954  Passo de Torres 1
-13.2021784 12.8724086  Passo de Torres 1
-13.2594776 13.5083692  Passo de Torres 1
-14.1198085 14.9667616  Passo de Torres 1
-14.38885   14.2428658  Passo de Torres 1
-16.3829466 9.2196328   Praia Grande    1
-13.8294    12.750148   Praia Grande    1
-14.7768832 12.3515168  Praia Grande    1
-14.330768  12.4748048  Praia Grande    1
-14.1199888 12.3936402  Praia Grande    1
-15.8021972 8.9641912   Praia Grande    1
-13.7256085 14.1121912  Praia Grande    1
-13.7485672 14.3076864  Praia Grande    1
-13.2635704 14.1915902  Praia Grande    1
-13.435468  13.7385068  Praia Grande    1
-13.5920176 13.3388482  Praia Grande    1
-13.1899    13.5998078  Praia Grande    1
-13.4620712 13.8104248  Praia Grande    1
-13.742428  13.4159032  Praia Grande    1
-14.0094832 12.755285   Praia Grande    1
-13.6646648 13.1847382  Praia Grande    1
-13.819168  12.4295992  Praia Grande    1
-13.3423568 13.063505   Praia Grande    1
-13.8590728 11.799803   Praia Grande    1
-13.686152  12.1306258  Praia Grande    1
-15.7478545 12.1136995  Praia Grande    1
-15.084613  12.8002597  Praia Grande    1
-15.291568  12.3242308  Praia Grande    1
-15.973534  12.8396695  Praia Grande    1
-15.5822905 13.2119884  Praia Grande    1
-16.1420545 11.2622404  Praia Grande    1
-15.055048  11.0807479  Praia Grande    1
-14.9180635 11.2197193  Praia Grande    1
-15.210757  12.2889694  Praia Grande    1
-14.4253135 14.0323345  Praia Grande    1
-14.773195  14.5519216  Praia Grande    1
-14.434183  12.4331263  Praia Grande    1
-14.9963    13.58261    Praia Grande    1
-15.1633    13.19701    Praia Grande    1
-15.2433    12.99654    Praia Grande    1
-14.6367    13.49158    Praia Grande    1
-14.9222    13.107  Praia Grande    1
-15.0408    12.99245    Praia Grande    1
-14.9341    12.972  Praia Grande    1
-14.7898    12.32865    Praia Grande    1
-14.6278    10.83741    Praia Grande    1
-15.5437    13.19394    Praia Grande    1
-15.3016    13.97741    Itapeva 1
-15.2058    13.52635    Itapeva 1
-15.0151    14.21777    Itapeva 1
-14.7552    13.99991    Itapeva 1
-15.1959    13.47214    Itapeva 1
-15.4043    13.76671    Itapeva 1
-15.2423    13.70739    Itapeva 1
-15.3046    13.58261    Itapeva 1
-15.0931    13.99275    Itapeva 1
-13.067116  14.034398   Itapeva 1
-13.2072944 14.096042   Itapeva 1
-13.6646648 13.8063152  Itapeva 1
-14.276503  14.8682371  Itapeva 1
-14.745601  14.0976718  Itapeva 1
-15.33493   13.8072838  Itapeva 1
-14.7544705 14.1899737  Itapeva 1
-14.869774  12.8770051  Itapeva 1
-15.068845  12.1894078  Itapeva 1
-14.0192875 13.1279833  Praia das Cabras    1
-14.319865  12.7587757  Praia das Cabras    1
-14.2873435 13.0968703  Praia das Cabras    1
-14.0468815 11.6013721  Praia das Cabras    1
-14.7544705 13.7243158  Praia das Cabras    1
-13.9286215 13.8622501  Praia das Cabras    1
-14.258764  13.2949564  Praia das Cabras    1
-13.693087  11.7590113  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.866535  11.3317261  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.01436   11.7818275  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.8497815 12.3273421  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.9365055 11.9861362  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.622131  12.388531   Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.19175   12.7774435  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.1730255 11.880352   Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.0409685 12.0856978  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.8103615 12.0753268  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.4607915 11.5868527  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.258764  11.4292135  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.138533  12.0307315  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.0961565 10.9438507  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.894129  11.7268612  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.8364    13.00063    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.6892    13.3402 Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.7139    13.07632    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.6082    13.107  Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.7336    12.75925    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.5864    13.27065    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.4837    12.97813    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-13.8364    12.82471    Lagoa do Peixe  1
-14.1644    12.89835    Lagoa do Peixe  1
```

Comment: First, put the data in the question. We do not have access to your `siber_local_temporada_names.csv` file. Second, do you absolutely have to do this chart using the `SIBER` package? Show us what you want to achieve. Perhaps this can be done using `ggplot2`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you use the `ggplot2` package. You don't even need to use the `SIBER` package here.
See how easy it can be!

```
library(tidyverse)

dados = tribble(
  ~iso1, ~iso2, ~group, ~community,
  -13.051768, 13.1703546, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.2236656, 12.5025446, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.0476752, 12.6545998, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.03642, 13.1035736, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.0118632, 13.0593954, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.2021784, 12.8724086, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -13.2594776, 13.5083692, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -14.1198085, 14.9667616, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -14.38885, 14.2428658, "Passo de Torres", 1,
  -16.3829466, 9.2196328, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.8294, 12.750148, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.7768832, 12.3515168, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.330768, 12.4748048, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.1199888, 12.3936402, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.8021972, 8.9641912, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.7256085, 14.1121912, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.7485672, 14.3076864, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.2635704, 14.1915902, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.435468, 13.7385068, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.5920176, 13.3388482, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.1899, 13.5998078, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.4620712, 13.8104248, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.742428, 13.4159032, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.0094832, 12.755285, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.6646648, 13.1847382, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.819168, 12.4295992, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.3423568, 13.063505, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.8590728, 11.799803, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -13.686152, 12.1306258, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.7478545, 12.1136995, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.084613, 12.8002597, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.291568, 12.3242308, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.973534, 12.8396695, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.5822905, 13.2119884, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -16.1420545, 11.2622404, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.055048, 11.0807479, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.9180635, 11.2197193, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.210757, 12.2889694, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.4253135, 14.0323345, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.773195, 14.5519216, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.434183, 12.4331263, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.9963, 13.58261, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.1633, 13.19701, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.2433, 12.99654, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.6367, 13.49158, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.9222, 13.107, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.0408, 12.99245, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.9341, 12.972, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.7898, 12.32865, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -14.6278, 10.83741, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.5437, 13.19394, "Praia Grande", 1,
  -15.3016, 13.97741, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.2058, 13.52635, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.0151, 14.21777, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.7552, 13.99991, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.1959, 13.47214, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.4043, 13.76671, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.2423, 13.70739, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.3046, 13.58261, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.0931, 13.99275, "Itapeva", 1,
  -13.067116, 14.034398, "Itapeva", 1,
  -13.2072944, 14.096042, "Itapeva", 1,
  -13.6646648, 13.8063152, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.276503, 14.8682371, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.745601, 14.0976718, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.33493, 13.8072838, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.7544705, 14.1899737, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.869774, 12.8770051, "Itapeva", 1,
  -15.068845, 12.1894078, "Itapeva", 1,
  -14.0192875, 13.1279833, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -14.319865, 12.7587757, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -14.2873435, 13.0968703, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -14.0468815, 11.6013721, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -14.7544705, 13.7243158, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -13.9286215, 13.8622501, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -14.258764, 13.2949564, "Praia das Cabras", 1,
  -13.693087, 11.7590113, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.866535, 11.3317261, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.01436, 11.7818275, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.8497815, 12.3273421, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.9365055, 11.9861362, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.622131, 12.388531, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.19175, 12.7774435, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.1730255, 11.880352, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.0409685, 12.0856978, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.8103615, 12.0753268, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.4607915, 11.5868527, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.258764, 11.4292135, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.138533, 12.0307315, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.0961565, 10.9438507, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.894129, 11.7268612, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.8364, 13.00063, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.6892, 13.3402, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.7139, 13.07632, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.6082, 13.107, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.7336, 12.75925, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.5864, 13.27065, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.4837, 12.97813, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -13.8364, 12.82471, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1,
  -14.1644, 12.89835, "Lagoa do Peixe", 1) %>% 
  mutate(group = group %>% fct_inorder())


dados %>% ggplot(aes(iso1, iso2, fill = group, colour = group))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  stat_ellipse()+
  xlab(expression({delta}^13*C~'\u2030'))+
  ylab(expression({delta}^15*N~'\u2030'))
```

Here's a beautiful graph with ellipses that preserve the colors of the points and ellipses. If this color palette does not suit you, you can always change it manually.
[image]
I hope this is what you expected and my answer solves your problem.